# This sentence seems too ambiguous to me. I don't get the meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

"But in the harsh light of hindsight it's uncomfortable how often the writers' stabs at bitter-little-pill realism - a sort of kitchen-sink Tolkien - tip over into edgy nihilism for nihilsm's sake."

I was reading an article on this [link](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2020-05-19-what-the-witcher-3-got-right), and I encountered a sentence, which seems very odd to me. I'm not a native English speaker, and this sentence is beyond me.
I know the `in the hindsight` part and all that, but this part confuses me: "it's uncomfortable how often the writers' stabs at bitter-little-pill realism - a sort of kitchen-sink Tolkien - tip over into edgy nihilism for nihilsm's sake"

I searched the bitter-little-pill thing and I feel like it's like a hard job that you'd need to do (or sth like that) but the stabbing parts make me confused. Does it mean that the writers tried to evade the bitter-little-pill realism or did they actually engage with it? I know the kitchen-sink part too, but the whole sentence seems odd to me. Can you translate it to some low-level English please?

Comment: Here “stabs” means “(low effort) attempts”. The writers are making poor attempts to depict realism in their stories, by injecting the inevitable hard choices and unforeseen consequences we face in real life. They are attempting — and failing — to emulate the famous writer Tolkien’s success in this area, by taking his approach of depicting these hard choices & consequences, but not using his judicious selection of elements to include and more importantly exclude. They aim for realism and, overshoot, and fall into the juvenile chasm of nihilism.

Comment: Even simpler: writers trying to be bold can go too far and end up being mean. *Take this, who cares!*

Comment: You are having difficulty  because that sentence is abominable. It puts metaphor on top of metaphor and smashes them into a mix of figures of speech. There is barely a single word used in a simple way. The author does what he is complaining about. It is barely decodable, though @DanBron does a fine job.